# Knockout validation inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, modal-dialog, knockout-validation

For my view; I have a simple textbox as below.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: vm().dummyValidationTest">
```

in the viewmodel, I have observable defined as

```
dummyValidationTest = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
```

Finally, I apply binding as

```
 ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(vm);
```

This validation works great when textbox is on the main form; however as soon as I move textbox inside Bootstrap Modal defined as below validation does not work.

```
 <div class="modal" id="startNewApp-modal">
```

Any thoughts why validations won't work inside Modal Window?

Both base page and modal are defined in same View.

EDIT: Please see jsfiddle below example

1. No modal, validation working: http://jsfiddle.net/athekdi/y53V2/
2. With modal, validation not working: http://jsfiddle.net/athekdi/6W5xH/1/

Comment: How are you showing the modal?

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle without modal when validation is working: http://jsfiddle.net/athekdi/y53V2/; and this is the jsfiddle with modal and validation is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/athekdi/6W5xH/1/

Comment: Your example is working fine, if you reference the validation plugin correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/35MDq/. So first your should reference KO and only after that the validation plugin.

Comment: in my application code, I do have knockout.validation.js after knockout-2.3.0.js; it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `validation library reference` after KO since it depends on that library

http://jsfiddle.net/6W5xH/2/

Comment: in my application code, I do have knockout.validation.js after knockout-2.3.0.js; it's still not working.

Comment: Your Fiddle works so your app code must differ from fiddle code

Comment: If it's a library reference order issue; how come it is working here http://jsfiddle.net/athekdi/y53V2/ where validation library is referenced before KO

Comment: because you use jsfiddles version of KO in that one and its loaded before the external ones